# Using another scope object values within the ng-repeat of some other scope object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, string-interpolation

I have set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thomsebastin/2q96pfpf/1/) to explain my question well. I would like to display the names from the `$scope.gem` inside `ng-repeat` [only one name for each ng-repeat and don't loop all] of `$scope.knobItems` without extending the `knobItems` scope. I want this to be made possible by maintaining the exact structure of controller as it is now. I am new to angular. I just wanna know if this is possible in angular and if is a good practice.

**view**

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="Mycont">
        <div ng-repeat="knobs in knobItems">
            <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in knobItems.nums">{{value.knobTitle}} : {{value.knobColor}}
                <div ng-bind="gem[0].name"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**controller**

```
var ngMod = angular.module("myapp", []);
ngMod.controller("Mycont", function ($scope) {
    $scope.knobItems = {};
    $scope.knobItems.nums = [{
        knobTitle: "Company Profile",
        knobColor: "#f46607"
    }, {
        knobTitle: "Deals left This Month",
        knobColor: "#ffcc00"
    }, {
        knobTitle: "Pricelist",
        knobColor: "#f40787"
    }, {
        knobTitle: "Pictures",
        knobColor: "#a1b80a"
    }, {
        knobTitle: "Videos",
        knobColor: "#14b9d6"
    }];
    $scope.gem = [{
        name: "Thomas"
    }, {
        name: "Sebastian"
    }, {
        name: "June"
    }, {
        name: "Yuvan"
    }];
});
```

**intended output**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy fix: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2q96pfpf/4/)

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="Mycont">
        <div ng-repeat="knobs in knobItems">
            <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in knobItems.nums">{{value.knobTitle}} : {{value.knobColor}}
                <div ng-bind="gem[$index].name"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is awesomely simple. Can I use the same technique if I have to get the value as an attribute value of first `ng-repeat`, something like `<div ng-repeat="knobs in knobItems" fg-color="gem[$index].name">` hope you got my idea.

Comment: Thanks Mikey, marking this the answer. And sorry Chris for misleading you. Your answer helps as well.

Answer (score 1):

The output in you fiddle is exactly the same without the first ng-repeat: http://jsfiddle.net/2nrbrfxL/

Going by you description rather than you code:

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="Mycont">
        <div ng-repeat="knobs in knobItems">
            <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in knobs">{{value.knobTitle}} : {{value.knobColor}}
                <div ng-repeat="gemItem in gem">{{gemItem.name}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p2fuq2du/

Comment: Can I achieve the same if `{{gemItem.name}}` is an attribute of first `ng-repeat` div, like `<div ng-repeat="knobs in knobItems" fg-color={{gemItem.name}}>` ?

Comment: Sorry Chris, I din't frame the question well. I have made an edit and added an image as well to show what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div ng-app="myapp">
        <div ng-controller="Mycont">
             <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in knobItems.nums">{{value.knobTitle}} : {{value.knobColor}}
                 <div ng-bind="gem[key].name"></div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I checked the documentation and they have used `$index` there. I ll stick to that as long as that works. But hey, thanks for the answer. I hope this works as well.

Comment: Yes sure, Documentation provide the exact solution. Go ahead with it.